# want to add unique array in list<>

Tags: c#, list

i want to add unique array in list.below is the code i have tried so far.

but it is not working as per my requirement.

------global class-----

```
    public class filesdetail
        {
            public string truckno { get; set; }
            public string deliveryno { get; set; }
        }
```

-----define list globaly-----

```
      public List<filesdetail> arrr_lst_truck_del;
```

-------code in event-------

```
      arrr_lst_truck_del = new List<filesdetail>();
      for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
                {

                    if (temp[i].Split(Convert.ToChar(9)).Length > 1)
                    { 
                        obj = new filesdetail();
                        obj.truckno = temo1;
                        obj.deliveryno = temp[i].Split(Convert.ToChar(9))[0].Trim('\n');
                        if (!arrr_lst_truck_del.Contains(obj))
                        {
                            arrr_lst_truck_del.Add(obj);
                        }                            
                    }
                }
```

Comment: How is it "not working per your requirement"? What are your requirements? What's the exception/error?

Comment: @DaveZych: want to add unique array inspite of condition !Contains() it allows me to add same array in list..... code working fine no error or execption is there.

Comment: have you heard of the .Distinct() method that is available for lists

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse : and do you know when one use .Disticnt() method?? here i am inserting values in list instead of getting from it.

Comment: once you populate your list just do something like this `MyList = MyList.Distinct()` you will eliminate all redundant elements from the list

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the `Equals(object)` method on your `filesdetail` class, which `Contains` can then use to check if two `filesdetail`s match.

The default `Equals` method only returns `true` if the objects are exactly the same object, so if you do:

```
new filesdetail().Equals(new filesdetail())
```

... this will never be true.

Here is an example implementation. It's a good practice to implement `IEquatable<T>` to indicate that you have a sane equality method. I've also implemented `GetHashCode` for good measure:

```
public class filesdetail : IEquatable<filesdetail>
{
    public string truckno { get; set; }
    public string deliveryno { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(filesdetail other)
    {
        return other != null &&
                Equals(truckno, other.truckno) &&
                Equals(deliveryno, other.deliveryno);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as filesdetail);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var trucknoHash = truckno == null ? 0 : truckno.GetHashCode();
        var deliverynoHash = deliveryno == null ? 0 : deliveryno.GetHashCode();

        return (trucknoHash*397) ^ deliverynoHash;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try Distinct method

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<filesdetail> details = new List<filesdetail>();
        details.Add(new filesdetail() { truckno = "123", deliveryno = "abc" });
        details.Add(new filesdetail() { truckno = "123", deliveryno = "abc" });
        var a = details.Distinct(new filesdetailComparer<filesdetail>()).ToList();
    }
}

public class filesdetailComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        var obj1 = x as filesdetail;
        var obj2 = y as filesdetail;

        if (obj1 != null && obj2 != null && string.Compare(obj1.deliveryno, obj2.deliveryno) == 0 && string.Compare(obj1.truckno, obj2.truckno) == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        var obj1 = obj as filesdetail;
        //Check whether the object is null 
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, null)) return 0;

        //Get hash code for the truckno field if it is not null. 
        int hashtruckno = obj1.truckno == null ? 0 : obj1.deliveryno.GetHashCode();

        //Get hash code for the deliveryno field. 
        int hashdeliveryno = obj1.deliveryno == null ? 0 : obj1.deliveryno.GetHashCode();

        //Calculate the hash deliveryno for the filesdetail. 
        return hashtruckno ^ hashdeliveryno;
    }
}

public class filesdetail
{
    public string truckno { get; set; }
    public string deliveryno { get; set; }
}
```